Ideas for how to graphically represent an increase in spending in a budgeting app?
I'm struggling with how to develop the combo of graphics and UX writing to communicate at a glance that you are trending over budget because your spending this month thus far is outpacing your spending during the same period last month. I'm experimenting with up/down arrows versus +/- signs and with different wording like "[up]$350. You've spent $400. Last month during this period you spent $50" or "Last month $50. This month $400. +$350" See https://xd.adobe.com/view/af597bfc-9a3a-47c6-b354-565ef3a4cb08-fa0a/ It's a prototype for my portfolio that is a tweaked version of an instructor's basic design with some UX improvements for a budgeting app. It is far from fully developed, but the basic premise is there, which is the app lets you know if this month you are spending more or less compared to what you spent last month so that you are able to adjust your spending behavior. Would love your ideas!

Please add images instead of a link. Also, is there a specific problem to solve or question to answer? Asking for ideas is not what this site is for. See the help section: https://ux.stackexchange.com/help
